# Best way to write a long expression

Tags: align

I solved a system of equation and got 32 solution for each variable but latex made me sick because I can't find a way to output the result.

```
\subsection{EPs with CFR}
\subsubsection{y1=0 and solving the rest of the system by symbolic matlab}
 \paragraph*{x1}
\begin{align*}
 x_{1}^{(1)}=\quad& \frac{N\,\epsilon _{1}\,r_{1}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,f_{11}+K_{22}\,N\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,y_{2}}{K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,{f_{11}}^2+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,r_{1}}\\
 x_{1}^{(i=2,3,4,5,9,12,13,14,15,19,22,24,25,28,30,31)}=\quad& 0\\ 
 x_{1}^{(7)}=\quad& \frac{N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{41}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{41}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}}{\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}}\\ 
x_{1}^{(32)}=\quad&-\frac{Nu_{1}^{(32)}}{D_{1}^{(32)}}
D_{1}^{(32)}=\quad&\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}
\end{align*}
```

I keep getting errors like :

```
Dimension too large. \end{align*}
```

or

```
Huge page cannot be shipped out.
```

and nothing comes out. I tried to split using multiple align but no result.

Is a way to get around with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It often works better to set such large mechanically generated expressions using inline textstyle math which allows line breaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\subsection{EPs with CFR}
\subsubsection{y1=0 and solving the rest of the system by symbolic matlab}
 \paragraph*{x1}

 \begin{flushleft}
 \def\frac#1#2{(#1)/(#2)}
$
x_{1}^{(1)}=\quad \frac{N\,\epsilon _{1}\,r_{1}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,f_{11}+K_{22}\,N\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,y_{2}}{K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,{f_{11}}^2+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,r_{1}}$\\
$x_{1}^{(i=2,3,4,5,9,12,13,14,15,19,22,24,25,28,30,31)}=\quad 0$\\ 
$x_{1}^{(7)}=\quad \frac{N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N^2\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{41}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{41}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,g_{12}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,g_{12}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}\,y_{2}}{\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}}$\\
$x_{1}^{(32)}=\quad-\frac{Nu_{1}^{(32)}}{D_{1}^{(32)}}
D_{1}^{(32)}=\quad\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{11}}^2\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{21}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,{f_{31}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,{f_{41}}^2\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{11}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{21}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{21}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{14}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{31}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{44}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{34}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{31}\,\eta _{24}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{31}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{31}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{2}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{11}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{12}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{13}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{21}\,f_{41}\,r_{1}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{21}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{43}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{22}\,\eta _{33}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}-K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{31}\,\eta _{42}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}+K_{22}\,N\,\beta _{41}\,\eta _{23}\,\eta _{32}\,\eta _{41}\,f_{11}\,f_{41}\,r_{2}\,r_{3}\,r_{4}
$
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got error messages.   Missing { inserted. \end{align*}
`You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. \def\frac#1#2{(#1)}{(#`    Missing $ inserted. ...^2+\epsilon _{1}\,\eta _{11}\,r_{1}} $\\

Comment: @F.O you do not get that error from the code posted above.

Comment: @F.O your fragment of error message shows that you have `{}{}` in the wrong place.

Comment: I wrote the second line wrong that is why I got error message.But still it would have been better to get math mode not inline math mode .

Comment: @F.O  display math doesn't linebreak and neither do built up fractions, so if you want those and want them to fit on the page, then you need to specify some transformation that might possibly work. But this is what I would do (and have done when I was working with systems that generated large expressions)

Comment: This maybe the fastest way to do that.